# Read ublas vectors from binary file or init it with array[]

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

Why I cannot read ublas vectors from a binary file in a way like (instead of reading by one element at a time):

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> floatVector(10);
myFile.read( (char *)&vector, 10 * sizeof(double));
```

Is there a way to initialize ublas vector from the array?

```
double d[10];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
   double array[] = {1., 2., 3.};
   boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> v(sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array));
   std::copy(array, array + sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array), v.data().begin());
```